# MySQL: any way to have a column defaults to auto-increment (or copy from an auto-increment field) but still allow other values to be inserted?

Tags: mysql, database-design, auto-increment

I'm building a Q&A site. I want to store both questions and answers in the same table:

```
CREATE TABLE Q_n_A (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    question_id INT NOT NULL,
    # type indicates whether the record is a question (1) or an answer (0)
    type BOOL,
    title VARCHAR(80),
    body VARCHAR(5000)
);
```

When I insert a new question, I don't have a value of `question_id` for this new question. As such, I want to use the auto_incremented value of `id` as the value for `question_id`. So in this case I want `question_id` to either default to `AUTO_INCREMENT` or to copy from `id`.

When I insert an answer to an existing question, I already know what is the `question_id` for that answer. As such I want to specify a value for `question_id` at the insert.

Is there a way to do what I want here: default `question_id` to `AUTO_INCREMENT` (or copy from the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field `id`) but still allow non-default value of `question_id` to be specified?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not submit a proposal to Area 51?  http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: pretty sure you can (and should) use a `TRIGGER` for this. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE Q_n_A (
overall_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
parent_id INT default '0',
title VARCHAR(80),
body VARCHAR(5000)
);
```

Now when someone ask simply insert no parent_id, resulting it to have parent_id = 0
When someone answers insert into parent_id the ovverall_id, via $_POST data or however your form is setup.

Making it easy to query the correct answers to the given question